# How to set a custom title using Xamarin/Monodroid

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

Has anyone successfully set a custom title using MonoDroid?

This code fails:

```
base.OnCreate (bundle);     
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.WordSearchLayout);

//Customise the title bar
if (this.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle))
{               
    this.Window.SetFeatureInt (WindowFeatures.CustomTitle, Resource.Layout.custom_title);
}
```

Strangely, it fails on the call to `RequestFeature` with the exception `requestFeature() must be called!`.

```
I/MonoDroid(26052): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Exception of type 'Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException' was thrown.
I/MonoDroid(26052): at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallBooleanMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <0x0007c>
I/MonoDroid(26052): at Android.Views.Window.RequestFeature (Android.Views.WindowFeatures) <0x00157>
I/MonoDroid(26052): at com.xxx.android.WordSearchActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x0013b>
I/MonoDroid(26052): at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x0005f>
I/MonoDroid(26052): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.1a40b50f-d523-4f52-b291-bcedd3a88965 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00033>
I/MonoDroid(26052): 
I/MonoDroid(26052):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
I/MonoDroid(26052): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:181)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at com.xxx.android.WordSearchActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at com.xxx.android.WordSearchActivity.onCreate(WordSearchActivity.java:30)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1065)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914) 
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
I/MonoDroid(26052):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/mono    (26052):  
E/mono    (26052): Unhandled Exception: Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Exception of type 'Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException' was thrown.
E/mono    (26052):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallBooleanMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (26052):   at Android.Views.Window.RequestFeature (WindowFeatures featureId) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (26052):   at com.xxx.android.WordSearchActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (26052):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
E/mono    (26052):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:1a40b50f-d523-4f52-b291-bcedd3a88965 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
E/mono    (26052):   --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
E/mono    (26052): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
E/mono    (26052):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:181)
E/mono    (26052):  at com.xxx.andro
```

Changing the ordering of the code to call `SetContentView` (see below) has some effect:

```
 base.OnCreate (bundle);        

//Customise the title bar
if (this.Window.RequestFeature (WindowFeatures.CustomTitle))
{               
    this.Window.SetFeatureInt (WindowFeatures.CustomTitle, Resource.Layout.custom_title);
}   
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.WordSearchLayout);
```

This will result in an empty grey bar in the title, but nothing else.  custom_title is defined as:

```
<TextView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:id="@+id/myTitle" 
  android:text="This is my new title" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="50dp" 
  android:textColor="@android:color/black"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  android:layout_marginLeft="25px"
  android:paddingTop="3px" 
/>
```

Same result (grey bar) on emulator and device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my app i have used this code to setup custom title.

```
base.OnCreate (bundle);        
RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle);
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.WordSearchLayout);
Window.SetFeatureInt (WindowFeatures.CustomTitle, Resource.Layout.custom_title);
```

Comment: +1 for `RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle);` before the `SetContentView`!

Comment: @mironych How to set FEATURE_NO_TITLE