# MonoDroid Change Activity Label or Title Programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a gridview with pictures of equipment to select from.  Once selected, the user is taken to an activity that summarizes all the info they need to know for that model of equipment.  I'd like for the Label or Title of that activity to display the selected model of equipment.

It looks like in java to be as simple as setTitle(string), but this functionality doesn't seem to exist in mono.  Looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264077/how-to-set-a-custom-title-using-xamarin-monodroid), but you can only use integer or an existing drawable.  I need to set it to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set that via the [Title](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=P%3aAndroid.App.Activity.Title#) property. In general, where you see setFoo/getFoo methods in Java, those will be mapped to a property named Foo in C#.