# Monodroid change Activity Title from Fragment programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am trying to change the label of my activity from a fragment that is currently shown. I tried the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825392/monodroid-change-activity-label-or-title-programmatically) but it simply DOES NOT WORK :( I also tried to change the Title of the `ActionBar` property of the current activity, but that does not work also. Here is my code:

```
...
Console.WriteLine ("Changing title to: " + title);
Activity.ActionBar.Title = title;
Activity.Title = title;
...
```

In the console I see the following output:

```
Changing title to: hello
```

I also tried setting both separately, still does not work :( Any ideas?
Can the problem be somehow related to the xml layouts of the activity and the respective fragment? Here are their contents.

```
<!-- LAYOUT FOR THE RoutesActivity -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    tools:context=".RoutesActivity" />


<!-- LAYOUT FOR THE Fragment -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:tag="maptag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

** **EDIT 3 Nov 2013** **

I found out the problem - actually I set the visibility of the action bar title to false in the corresponding activity, so if you don't see your title, check your code for something like `ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to change the title in the main thread?

```
RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                Activity.ActionBar.Title = title;
                Activity.Title = title;
            });
```

Comment: It's interresting, it worked for me. Could you post some more code?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I finally found some time to dig further into this issue. I found out that I set the visibility of the action bar to FALSE in my activity by calling 'ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);' That was the actual problem at the beginning, I was just looking in the wrong place :(

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that you managed to solve the problem :)

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct anyway - thanks for the help ;)